# Adding new property using forEach in an array of objects

Tags: javascript-objects

I have 2 arrays of objects. I would like to add a category property to each object in values, example: 50 should fall in the range 41 to 70

```
let values = [
    {1: 124},
    {2: 50},
    {3: 65},
    {4: 21}
];

let categories = [
    {cat: "Category1", min: 5, max: 40},
    {cat: "Category2", min: 41, max: 70},
    {cat: "Category3", min: 71, max: 130}
];
```

How do I get my result as, using array method forEach():

```
[
    {1: 124, category: "Category3"},
    {2: 50, category: "Category2"},
    {3: 65, category: "Category2"},
    {4: 21, category: "Category1"}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an optimized one but satisfies the requirement.

```
let result = [];
values.forEach(element => {
    categories.forEach(col => {
        let current = Object.values(element)[0];
        if(current >= col.min && current <=col.max){ 
            element["category"] = col.cat;
        }
    })
    result.push(element);
})
```